# C#: How to prevent all "if" statements from being executed consecutively

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a C# program, using Visual Studio and the console template.  All of my if statements are running consecutively.  I want only one of the if statement's block scope to be evaluated if the conditional is true and for the others to be ignored when one is run.

Here is what I have:

```
Console.WriteLine("What is your age?");
string age = Console.ReadLine();

int ageInt;
Int32.TryParse(age, out ageInt);
if (ageInt >= 17)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You are rather young!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
if (ageInt >= 18)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You are young, but technically an adult!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
if (ageInt >= 21)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You are of legal drinking age! A semi-adult!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
if (ageInt >= 30)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You are a true adult!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

When it is supposed to show the message for each if statement, the console will just display the first if statement and then just run through each of the other if statements. Can anyone help me figure out how to change the code to do what I want?

**Solution:** All I needed to do was reverse the order of the if statements, and make every other if statement an "else if" statement like this:

```
if (ageInt == 100)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You are really old!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
else if (ageInt >= 62)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You should retire!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
else if (ageInt >= 30)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You are a true adult!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
else if (ageInt >= 21)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You are of legal drinking age! A semi-adult!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: what is the input you're receiving ?

Comment: use `else if` instead of `if` in all cases except the first one.

Comment: As @MarcinJuraszek said, but in addition you may want to reverse your `if` order.  Put `30` first; `17` last.  In other words, test age in _descending_ order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two things.

- Reverse the order of your checks. You want to check the most specific one first (i.e. above 30)
- Then use `else if` to ensure only one of the blocks gets executed.

The code would then look like this:

```
if (ageInt >= 30)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You are a true adult!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
else if (ageInt >= 21)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You are of legal drinking age! A semi-adult!");
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
// ...
```

Comment: This. This seems to work for me! I've reversed the order and tested maybe half of the ages, and it seems to work correctly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to flip the order, since if your age is > 30, all of those if checks will be run.